# Image Upload with Mootools

Tags: php, upload, mootools

I am creating an ajax uploader with mootools. When I remove the ajax and simply upload the form I get $_FILES with the file data present. But when I use the ajax version, the $_FILES super global is empty. Every other part of the form is present. It acts as if it does not send the image at all but only in the ajax version. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

```
<form id="uploadphoto_pod" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type='file' id='uploadphoto' name='uploadphoto'/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="add_product" value="Upload" />
  </form>
   <div id="response"><!-- Ajax Response --></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEvent('domready', function(){
$('uploadphoto').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
    //Prevents the default submit event from loading a new page.
    e.stop();
    //("this" refers to the $('uploadphoto') element).
    this.set('send', {onComplete: function(response) {
        $('response').set('html', response);
    }});
    //Send the form.
    this.send();
});
});
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the ["Form.Upload" Mootools Plugin](http://mootools.net/forge/p/form_upload) which does a nice HTML5 upload with auto fallback for older browser - it does the trick nicely, even implements multi file upload with drag & drop support, but sadly lacks a bit in extensibility - i'm currently trying to implement a function which lets me add additional form elements - currently, only file input fielts are being submitted.

Just a few minutes ago, i discovered [this simple and lean "File.Upload" Extension](https://gist.github.com/1342473) - this finally did the trick. It's very configurable and allows me to send additional fields to the receiving file of the form data. No multiple file selection though, but it seems perfect for simple one-file ajax uploads and can be triggered for example on the change event of the file selector input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Javascript alone. You will either need some sort of flash plugin like SWFUpload. Or use the new [XMLHTTPRequest v2](http://lenss.nl/2010/01/drag-drop-uploads-with-xmlhttprequest2-and-php/). The last one is not supported by all browsers yet. So stick with the first option for now.

Comment: you can do it with js alone in a browser that supports html5, actually. you can also use an iframe shim (google for AIM shim) or use harald's fancy uploader (via a .swf) http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/ also, check out thierry bela's http://mootools.net/forge/p/uploadmanager which uses html5 or the shim trick as fallback (so, progressive enhancement)